# loop list from global

Tags: tcl

I have a list with ftp servers. this can always change

liste :

```
set ftp1 "192.168.0.12 -u test,test"
set ftp2 "192.168.0.13 -u test,test"
set ftp3 "192.168.0.14 -u test,test"
```

and here a tcl code, i want in the tcl a look with all ftps from a list to exec not sequentially but multiplied

```
set ftp1 "192.168.0.12 -u test,test"
set ftp2 "192.168.0.13 -u test,test"
set ftp3 "192.168.0.14 -u test,test"

proc search {nick host handle channel text} {
    global ftp1 ftp2 ftp3
    set text [stripcodes bcru $text]
    set searchtext [lindex [split $text] 0];
    set ftp1 "192.168.0.12 -u test,test"
    set results [exec sh f.sh $ftp1 $searchtext]
    foreach elem $results {
        putnow "PRIVMSG$channel :ftp1 $elem"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and this 
http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how to post a good question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to write another few helper procedures. Those procedures should do the search for one site and provide the results back to your code by a callback (since we're talking asynchronous processing here).

```
# This is a fairly standard pattern for how to do async reading from a pipeline
# Only the arguments to [open |[list ...]] can be considered custom...

proc searchOneHost {hostinfo term callback} {
    set pipeline [open |[list sh f.sh $hostinfo $term]]
    fconfigure $pipeline -blocking 0
    fileevent $pipeline readable [list searchResultHandler $pipeline $callback]
}
proc searchResultHandler {pipeline callback} {
    if {[gets $pipeline line] >= 0} {
        uplevel "#0" [list {*}$callback $line]
    } elseif {[eof $pipeline]} {
        close $pipeline
    }
}

# The rest of this code is modelled on your existing code

set ftp1 "192.168.0.12 -u test,test"
set ftp2 "192.168.0.13 -u test,test"
set ftp3 "192.168.0.14 -u test,test"

proc search {nick host handle channel text} {
    set searchtext [lindex [split [stripcodes bcru $text]] 0]
    foreach v {ftp1 ftp2 ftp3} {
        upvar "#0" $v ftp
        searchOneHost $ftp $searchtext [list report $channel $v]
    }
}
proc report {channel name found} {
    foreach elem $found {
        putnow "PRIVMSG$channel :$name $elem"
    }
}
```

I've only quoted `#0` to work around the highlighter here.